# Where can I study Juche Idea in North Korea?

Tags: north-korea

I am interested in Juche Idea and want to learn more about it and the relationship between Juche and the North Korea political system.

Where can I find course about Juche Idea in North Korea.

[image]

Comment: Probably better to ask the North Korean tour guide once you get there.

Comment: Why the down vote ?

Comment: Where are you from? I beleive NK collaborates with Juche study groups in various parts of the world.

Comment: @Blackbird57 I guess that specific recommendations are considered OT otherwise people would be asking all sorts of unwelcome questions, perhaps it would be better to offer suggestions on how to search for such organizations and find contact information. Or ignore.

Comment: @blackbird in my case, it's analogous to asking where to study national socialism in 1938 Germany, or communism in 1930s USSR. If the OP really wants to study it, I'd suggest learning about it from defectors in South Korea, as they're more free to tell the truth about North Korea's ideology than those currently in North Korea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Below link is dead as reported by @gerrit, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304230616/http://pyongyangproject.org/) is an archived copy for reference.

---

[This](http://www.pyongyangproject.org) group in Vancouver Canada organizes some things that look like they might be what you're looking for. You could contact them and ask if they could customize something for you. I have no direct knowledge of them or what their political leanings might be, but they do arrange trips aimed at folks with academic credentials or connections.

> Our programs are open to all who are interested; however applicants affiliated with an institution of higher learning (university, college, academic institute, think-tank, etc) as a student, researcher, scholar, faculty member, etc will have priority. This also applies to recent university graduates (within five years of graduation or in-between programs).

Suggest searching for "**study tour**" and similar search terms and you may find other suppliers (maybe Japan or China). Not just for North Korea- this kind of trip tends to be more interesting than ones aimed strictly at sightseeing or tourism. Some years ago I was invited to a study tour organized through a think tank that offered receptions at various embassies and meetings with special interest groups- well worthwhile- about the only organized tour I've enjoyed.

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try contacting Kim Il Sung University.

I have heard of people doing academic exchanges there. They also offer a course on the Juche Ideology. I don't imagine they'll care too much if you're a student or not either.

http://www.ryongnamsan.edu.kp/univ/international/scholar/1

Of course if you just want to learn about Juche, there are study groups located internationally.
Here's one based in the UK: http://korea-dpr.co/users/jisge/index.htm